# woocommerce show/get product thumbnails

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to implement wooCommerce in a custom theme I am building based on bootstrap framework (because I'm picky about how things look) So what I am trying to do is relocate wooCommerce product thumbnail gallery images. I am aware of the various functions and hooks that are available through wooCommerce like the ones listed in the [wc-template-hooks.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/c980817f6df900e3f13095930b0bd445fff01faa/includes/wc-template-hooks.php) and they work great except in my particular situation. I used the `"woocommerce_before_main_content"` and `"woocommerce_after_main_content"`hooks to wrap the product info in my bootstrap frame like so...

```
...
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1"> *where I want my gallery images to go* </div>
  <div class="col-md-7 *woocommerce-main"> where my woocommerce product is loaded* </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"> *some other product info is loaded here* </div>
</div>...
```

What I have run into is that I can't seem to use any of the product hooks or functions until after the product section is called/loaded (which makes perfect sense of course) but I need to be able to load the product gallery images into the first column `"col-md-1"`... so my question is... how do I get the product gallery images before everything has completed loading or can I retroactively process what goes into the first column after everything has loaded?

Thanks

EDIT: complete woocommerce hooks in my functions.php

```
<?php
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails', 20 );

add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'underwire_wrapper_start', 10);
add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'underwire_wrapper_end', 10);

function underwire_wrapper_start() {
  echo '<div class="row">';
  if ( is_product() ) {
      echo '<div class="col-md-1">';
      echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();
      //woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails();
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="col-md-7 woocommerce-main">';
  } else {
    echo '<div class="col-sm-12 woocommerce-main">';
  }
}

function underwire_wrapper_end() {
  if ( is_product() ) {
    echo '</div> <!-- /.woocommerce-main --><div class="col-md-4">';
    woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs();
    //woocommerce_output_related_products();
    echo '</div></div>';
  } else {
    echo '</div> <!-- /.woocommerce-main --></div>';
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you post your hook complete code? The product is actually a post type, so it is known when a page is loaded.

Comment: Done. You will see where the line //woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails(); is commented out. Everything else is running smoothly. echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail(); is able to display the product featured image with no problem.

Comment: You could change your template overrides instead.

Comment: I'm familiar with template overrides but the same problem is encountered. I can't call the function to load the product gallery images before a certain point in the page. It seems the function/s I need to call haven't been defined or loaded yet and that appears to be the crux of the problem. Anymore ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1):

**2020 answer:** This is an old post, but for anyone reading this, I believe you can hook into any part of the product page, and then in your custom hook function, use something like this to access the photo ids, using the $product object:

```
// priority number at the end can be whatever you want
add_action('action_you_want_to_hook_into', 'your_custom_function', 10);

function your_custom_function() {
    global $product;
    image_ids[] = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();
    // do something with image_ids[]
}
```

hope this helps anyone who stumbles in here!

and here is a [useful list of functions you can call on $product](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-product-info-title-sku-desc-product-object/)